# Passing $_POST Variable Into a Function in Server Side

Tags: php

I need to pass some `$_POST` data receiving from front-end in a query string inside a function in server side but it looks empty when I try  to dump the query is not getting the `$_POST` value.

Here I tried to simulate the situati0n and as you can see I am getting  empty ``` `` ``` instead of `roads`

```
$roads = $_POST;
$roads['column'] = "roads";

function tatoo(){
$sql = "SELECT `$roads`  FROM country";
echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  

}
tatoo();
```

here is the Dumped SQL:

> string(19) "SELECT ``  FROM country"

again, this is just simulated situation and in reality the code looks like

```
$roads = $_POST['roads'];

function tatoo(){
$sql = "SELECT `$roads`  FROM country";
echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  

}
tatoo();
```

Comment: Show us the front end code. Also try with $_GET?

Comment: Did you really read the post bro?!

Comment: Have you checked if `$_POST['roads']` really contains the expected value? It probably seems to not be set. Your first snippet would not work at all, because your trying to concatenate the array to the string. And don't forget to pass the variable to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tatoo(){
    $roads =  $_POST["roads"];
    $sql = "SELECT `{$roads}`  FROM country";
    echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  
}
tatoo();
```

this is better.

```
$roads = mysql_real_espace_string($_POST["roads"]);

function tatoo($roads){
    $sql = "SELECT `{$roads}`  FROM country";
    echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  
}
tatoo($roads);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you know scope of variable, you need to either use global variable or pass as parameter while calling `tatoo` function and correct method would be passing as parameter

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['column'])){
    tatoo($_POST['column']);
}

function tatoo($column){
    $sql = "SELECT `$column`  FROM country";
    echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";..

}
```

Also your query seems to be vulnerable to ***sql injection***, also looks like you are not using papered statements which is really not a good idea.

Comment: I just test this , it is empty again!

Comment: @MonaCoder than problem is at elsewhere

Comment: @MonaCoder 
you can check to verify POST data with code
var_dump($_POST); die;

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you cannot use your variable inside the function you need to use globle $var inside function or passing $var as argument

**try this**

```
$roads = $_POST;
$roads['column'] = "roads";

function tatoo(){
    global $roads;
    $sql = "SELECT `$roads['column_name']`  FROM country";
    echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  

}
tatoo();
```

**OR**

```
$roads = $_POST;
$roads['column'] = "roads";

function tatoo($roads){
    $sql = "SELECT `$roads['column_name']`  FROM country";
    echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  

}
tatoo();
```

Comment: Thanks Seyed but this is the result `SELECT Array FROM country`

Comment: @MonaCoder what is hard for you to understand error ? dont you just at least read error rather than just throw whole syntex  here

Answer (score 0):

Try using a parameter in your function.

Something like this:

```
//$roads = $_POST['roads'];
$roads = "test";

function tatoo($param){
$sql = "SELECT `$param`  FROM country";
echo var_dump($sql)."<br>";  

}
tatoo($roads);
```

This was tested and it worked.

> string(27) "SELECT `test` FROM country"